RuntimeError: dot : expected both vectors to have same dtype, but found Float and Half - pytorch lightning
I have a pytorch lightning gan network which was running carefully on google colab GPU. but one day suddenly I received "RuntimeError: dot : expected both vectors to have same dtype, but found Float and Half" error on first convolution layer.
My dataset is "openclimatefix/nimrod-uk-1km", "sample" and my pytorch lightning version is 1.6.5.
I run my code on precision 16.

I suppose you are working with DGMR by openclimatefix. I am currently encountering the same issue when I move model's precision in Trainer to 16 bit.
32 precision works fine. I will let you know if I get it working for 16 bit precison.
